# Having problems with API call to Firebase

Tags: json, api, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

So basically I have created my database like this:

[image]

Now I want to do an API call to this URL and get the `Products array[]` (Later I deserialise it).

For some reason it returns this:

```
{"Website1":{"title":"wolf","url":"http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/3D-Cool-Image.jpg"},"Website2":{"title":"skull","url":"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/20/a5/8f/20a58f0af4c1784e45dc15a26c041303.jpg"}}
```

It should all be surrounded by `square brackets []`, but it's surrounded by `{}` instead. This messes up my JSON decoding. Basically the result I want is like the JSON placeholder [website](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/).

I've just started to learn Flutter so if there's a better way to do these things then I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I realised that I can import my own JSON file into the Firebase database. So what I did was create a Json file in code editor on my PC and then uploaded it into Firebase.